# Arvixe Hosting and Visual Studio SQL Server Database Projects

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I am using Arvixe to host my sql server and websites, and would like to begin managing my database with a Visual Studio SQL Server database project so that I can get some source control going on the backend.

When I try to script my database's CREATE TO statement or use Visual Studio's import wizard, I get a permissions error:

`Requires VIEW DEFINITION, ALTER ANY LOGIN, and SELECT ON sys.sql_expression_dependencies or be a member of db_owner role.`

Has anyone had any luck managing an Arvixe sql server database with Visual Studio Database Projects, or have any tips for using the tools without those permissions? Their Tech support has been unable to help so far.

Edit: I am a member of db_owner, but i think Arvixe restricts permissions since its a shared server instance.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have enough permission on database. you must to have db_owner permission.

Comment: I am a member of the db_owner role, but i think Arvixe restricts permissions since it is a shared server instance

Comment: you should run SQL Profiler and see what is happened.

Comment: I can't run a trace on the server. I'm not a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, and I don't have the ALTER TRACE permission.